# How do I create generic images/avatars like SO?

Tags: image, random

These profile images that each new user on here SO gets. How are they made? I mean, are they randomly generated somehow? I could use something like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are gravatars ("Globally Recognisable avatars.") Gravatar is a free web service.

See http://www.gravatar.com/.

> Setting up Gravatars on your site is easy; you don't even need an account! Plugins are available for leading blog software and content management systems, and our tutorials will have you running Gravatars in no time.

Answer (score 3):

This linux command will generate random `identicon`:

```
$ curl -s "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/`uuidgen | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG" | display
```